# SwiftUI View wrapped up in Menu doesn't resize

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I want to use View inside Menu and my View has `@State` property, but I faced the problem that view wrapped up in Menu doesn't resize. I checked documentation and didn't found nothing that can affect on view size inside Menu. Can somebody describe why Menu have this behavior and how to solve this moment?

```
import SwiftUI

struct MenuView: View {

@State var greeting: Greetings = .short

enum Greetings: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case short = "Hi"
    case medium = "Hello"
    case long = "Nice to see you"
    
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        Picker("Options", selection: $greeting) {
            ForEach(Greetings.allCases) { greeting in
                Text(greeting.rawValue).tag(greeting)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        Text("Greeting wrapped in menu:")
        Menu {
            Button("Send to Someone", action: {})
            Button("Save as PDF", action: {})
        } label: {
            Label(greeting.rawValue, systemImage: "doc.fill")
                .labelStyle(.titleOnly)
        }
        
        Text("Greeting without menu:")
        Text(greeting.rawValue)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Behavior by OS design. If you need different - create custom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you mean the text within the Menu Label is not growing or shrinking depending on which selection you make in the Picker.

This is because the size of the label is being set but not being changed. If you're okay with it, setting a `maxWidth` of `.infinity` on the frame of the Label gives you this capability.

```
Label(greeting.rawValue, systemImage: "doc.fill")
    .labelStyle(.titleOnly)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) <<-- This here
```

[image: showcasing the frame example]

Comment: Nice and concise answer. I just added alignment to .frame for more complex UI